# Show age from postgres database and then it's show days only

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm executing `SQL = "select age (date)" and it's output x year y month,` etc. and then I send data to views of Django template but it's show z days

here SQL, shows "26 years 3 Mons 7 days"

```
SELECT *,age(date_of_birth) 
FROM brs_cmu_passenger 
WHERE user_id_id=%s" %(request.user.id)
```

in html, shows "13651 days"

```
{% for u in profile %}
  <p> Age : {{ u.age }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I just want to show age in my template, but Django python can not calculate in the template.

ps. when i'm send age to template django. this is value in there. `age=datetime.timedelta(9587)`

Comment: If you're using django then you should try using the ORM. Either way, you should also show what you have tried and try to give a sensible title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function [`age`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) returns `interval` datatype.

In your case: `26 years 3 Mons 7 days` which is `datetime.timedelta(9587)`

---

You could use `EXTRACT` to get only years:

```
SELECT *,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(date_of_birth)) AS age 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up on this page while looking for something different. Although the question is four years old, I think one solution should perhaps be added: instead of calculating the date difference in the database, you could also use the built-in `timesince` Django template filter, which should give you an output similar to the string output of the PostgreSQL `age()` function, see also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince

Not sure when the filter was added, it definitely is available in Django 1.8 and 1.9.